# Difference between Unity Pro licenses?

Tags: android, unity, ios

What is the difference between the various Unity Pro licenses? What does Android or iOS pro give me that Unity Pro doesn't? And what is the point of getting Unity Pro if I only care about mobile platforms, besides Win 8/WP 8 which Pro now comes with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity has a full [comparison chart](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses) on their site. The differences are too extensive to list here.

iOS and Android are different flavors of Pro. Android gives you the ability to publish to Android. iOS gives you the ability to publish to iOS. They can be combined for the ability to publish to both.

You must get Unity Pro in order to have the additions of Android or iOS. They are "expansions" of Unity Pro.

So, if you only care about mobile, you still have to get Unity Pro in order to be able to add the iOS and Android options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked over those charts closely before asking before asking. I still think they should be more clear about the differences between their paid and free options. The free levels of Android and iOS publishing were only recently added, so maybe this is why it all looks a bit confused.

Comment: @Johnny4445 - I agree, it's not clear to me either.